# Replace text from <option> to <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace text from selected  to another  using "ondblclick" event and jQuery library. Here my simple html code:

```
<input id="text_inp" >
<select id="info" ondblclick="PutValue()" >
   <option val="1">1</option>
   <option val="2">2</option>
   <option val="3">3</option>
</select>
```

And jQuery code:

```
    function PutValue(){
        var _val = $(this).text();
        $("#text_inp").val(_val);
    }
```

And console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the TypeError you are getting is not related to PutValue() function at all.

Comment: @HenriHietala the type error is comming due to input html, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will be are using the inline method you have to pass the element that you are clicking

```
<input id="text_inp" >
<select id="info" ondblclick="PutValue(this)" > <!-- put this as a parameter -->
   <option val="1">1</option>
   <option val="2">2</option>
   <option val="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Then in your function you'll be getting it

```
function PutValue(t) { // here t is the element / this
    var _val = $(t).val(); // to get the currently selected value use val
    $("#text_inp").val(_val);
}
```

---

Since you are using jQuery you should do it the jQuery way

```
$('#info').dblclick(function(){
   var _val = $(this).val();
   $("#text_inp").val(_val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks men. Work like a charm.

Comment: Still didn't understand differents to call function with 'this' and with out it.

Comment: @dantey89 if you are using inline handlers you have to specify on which element you fired the event by passing this to the function. When using jQuery, jQuery will do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of a option using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
function PutValue(){
    var _val = $(this).val();
    $("#text_inp").val(_val);
}
```

*BTW In Safari it's not possible to double click a select.*

Using the inline event handlers like `ondblclick` is bad practice, better do something like:

```
$("#info").dblclick(function(){ 

        var _val = $(this).val();
        $("#text_inp").val(_val);

});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2xRX/1/ (on change event)

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly define the type of input:

Replace this:

```
<input id="text_inp" >
```

With this:

```
<input id="text_inp" type="text" />
```